# Вопрос с отображение при использовании JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql

В поле dolzhn_atest.KOD_C содержится множество строк, но совпадение с полем kdpr.KDNSLP лиш по одной. В итоге отображается одна строка, а необходимо отобразить все. Час сижу не могу понять, пробывал left join, не помогло.

```
select  kdpr.N_KDK, --табельный номер
        ltrim(rtrim(kdpr.fam))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(kdpr.nam))+ ' ' +ltrim(rtrim(kdpr.otch)) as FIO, --ФИО
        slp.NSLP, --Должность
        dolzhn_atest.NAIM as Doljnost_po_atest, -- Должн по асестац.
        kategor.NAIM as Kategor, --категория
        KDK.GR_INVA --инвалидность

from kdpr 
inner join dbo.SLP on KDPR.KSLP = slp.KSLP
inner join dbo.sp2 as dolzhn_atest on dolzhn_atest.KOD_C = kdpr.KDNSLP
inner join dbo.sp2 as kategor on kategor.KOD_C = kdpr.KK36
inner join dbo.KDK on KDK.N_KDK = KDPR.N_KDK
where  dolzhn_atest.spr = 'dnslp'
    and kategor.SPR='k36'
```

Comment: @Владислав Сергеевич, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where  dolzhn_atest.spr = 'dnslp' and kategor.SPR='k36'` - если это условие выполняется только для одной строки - то и выдастся только одна строка. 
Если надо, чтобы из dolzhn_atest отобрались только записи с spr='dnslp' и это заджойнилось с kpdr - то тогда надо написать что-то такое:

```
select  kdpr.N_KDK, --табельный номер
        ltrim(rtrim(kdpr.fam))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(kdpr.nam))+ ' ' +ltrim(rtrim(kdpr.otch)) as FIO, --ФИО
        slp.NSLP, --Должность
        dolzhn_atest.NAIM as Doljnost_po_atest, -- Должн по асестац.
        kategor.NAIM as Kategor, --категория
        KDK.GR_INVA --инвалидность

from kdpr 
inner join dbo.SLP on KDPR.KSLP = slp.KSLP
left join dbo.sp2 as dolzhn_atest on dolzhn_atest.KOD_C = kdpr.KDNSLP and dolzhn_atest.spr = 'dnslp'
inner join dbo.sp2 as kategor on kategor.KOD_C = kdpr.KK36
inner join dbo.KDK on KDK.N_KDK = KDPR.N_KDK
where kategor.SPR='k36'
```

Comment: нет, результат такой-же

Comment: дописал пару встроеных delect и всё вышло

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1188/2 - так?

Comment: Немного подправил, но в целом да, спасибо. как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: только вот kategor.NAIM AS Kategor в вашем примере возвращяет NULL значения, пришлось подправить,а так спс